# Is This Black Foil in Front of the Membrane Part of the Speaker?

Tags: speakers

I bought mini speakers from Kepo (KP3246SP1), they have some kind of black foil in front of the speaker membrane. See the picture below:

[image]

**Is this black foil part of the speaker, or is it packaging and has to be removed?**

In case it is part of the speaker, what ist the function of this black foil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the speaker. It looks to me like a thin woven material, not an impermeable foil. It's there to protect the speaker cone and to keep dust out. Don't remove it!